# Xbox 360 voice problem

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues, voice-chat

I have just set up my Xbox 360 on Live, but cannot hear other players' voices through the TV or headset. Any help? I have tried changing the settings but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you say other players do you mean friends or just players in game? If it's in game is it for all games that you have tried?

This probably can occure when your NAT is "moderate" if that is the case that can prevent you from talking to other people, this has happened frequently for me. Try doing a test of your network settings. If you can resolve that issue then you will probably be able to use the "talk" functionality.